# 'NestMiddleware<any, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Function | Type<any>'

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am injecting a middleware into a module.

I'm getting a type error when I call `consumer.apply(middleware)`:

**Code:**

```
@Module({
  ...
})
export class FooModule implements NestModule {

  @Inject(FOO_MIDDLEWARE)
  private middleware: NestMiddleware;

  public configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(this.middleware)
      .forRoutes('foo');
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'NestMiddleware<any, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Function | Type<any>'.   Type 'NestMiddleware<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Type<any>': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I did:

- `private middleware: Type<any>`

Instead of:

- `private middleware: NestMiddleware`

Importing `Type` from `@nestjs/common`.